# Python: Determining period of the day based on hour using a for loop and conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to name the period of the day based on hourly information to my dataframe.

For this, I am attempting the following:

```
day_period = []

for index,row in df.iterrows():
        
    hour_series = row["hour"]
    
    # Morning = 04:00-10:00
    #if hour_series >= 4 and hour_series < 10:
    if 4 >= hour_series < 10:
        day_period_str = "Morning"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)
    
    # Day = 10:00-16:00
    #if hour_series >= 10 and hour_series < 16:
    if 10 >= hour_series < 16:
        day_period_str = "Day"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)
        
    # Evening = 16:00-22:00
    #if hour_series >= 16 and hour_series < 22:
    if 16 >= hour_series < 22:
        day_period_str = "Evening"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)
        
    # Night = 22:00-04:00
    #if hour_series >= 22 and hour_series < 4:
    if 22 >= hour_series < 4:
        day_period_str = "Night"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)
```

However, when double-checking if the length of my day_period list is the same as that of my dataframe (df)... they differ and they shouldn't. I can't spot the mistake. How can I fix the code?

```
len(day_period)
>21882

len(df)
>25696
```

Here's a preview of the data:

```
    timestamp               latitude    longitude   hour    weekday
0   2021-06-09 08:12:18.000 57.728867   11.949463   8   Wednesday
1   2021-06-09 08:12:18.000 57.728954   11.949368   8   Wednesday
2   2021-06-09 08:12:18.587 57.728867   11.949463   8   Wednesday
3   2021-06-09 08:12:18.716 57.728954   11.949368   8   Wednesday
4   2021-06-09 08:12:33.000 57.728905   11.949309   8   Wednesday
```

My end goal is to then append this list to the dataframe.

Comment: If your goal is to add a column to the dataframe, you should really go with a pandas specific way, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68603214/16343464). Looping manually through the rows is often inefficient and considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing a bit, it seems like the issue is the 22-4 block and separating them fixes this.

Also, I changed the `>=` to `<=`.

Using this code, it works as expected:

```
day_period = []


for index,row in df.iterrows():
    hour_series = row["hour"]

    # Night 1 = 00:00-04:00
    #if hour_series <= 0 and hour_series < 4:
    if 0 <= hour_series < 4:
        day_period_str = "Night"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)

    # Morning = 04:00-10:00
    #if hour_series <= 4 and hour_series < 10:
    elif 4 <= hour_series < 10:
        day_period_str = "Morning"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)
    
    # Day = 10:00-16:00
    #if hour_series <= 10 and hour_series < 16:
    elif 10 <= hour_series < 16:
        day_period_str = "Day"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)
        
    # Evening = 16:00-22:00
    #if hour_series <= 16 and hour_series < 22:
    elif 16 <= hour_series < 22:
        day_period_str = "Evening"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)
        
    # Night 2 = 22:00-24:00
    #if hour_series <= 22 and hour_series < 24:

    elif 22 <= hour_series < 24:
        day_period_str = "Night"
        day_period.append(day_period_str)

print(len(all_rows))
print(len(day_period)) # they should match now
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `pandas`, you should go with [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

input:

```
pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2021-07-31', '2021-08-01', freq='2h')})
```

```
ranges = {4: 'Night', 10: 'Morning', 16: 'Day', 22: 'Evening', 24: 'Night'}

df['time_of_day'] = pd.cut(df['date'].dt.hour,
                           bins=[-1]+list(ranges),
                           labels=ranges.values(),
                           right=False,
                           ordered=False, # because label "Night" is duplicated
                          )
```

output:

```
                  date time_of_day
0  2021-07-31 00:00:00       Night
1  2021-07-31 02:00:00       Night
2  2021-07-31 04:00:00     Morning
3  2021-07-31 06:00:00     Morning
4  2021-07-31 08:00:00     Morning
5  2021-07-31 10:00:00         Day
6  2021-07-31 12:00:00         Day
7  2021-07-31 14:00:00         Day
8  2021-07-31 16:00:00     Evening
9  2021-07-31 18:00:00     Evening
10 2021-07-31 20:00:00     Evening
11 2021-07-31 22:00:00       Night
12 2021-08-01 00:00:00       Night
```

Answer (score 0):

Your less than/greater than's are incorrect:

To find between 4 and 10 you want:

```
if 4 <= hour_series < 10:
```

Comment: yes I noticed this silly mistake after posting. I was initially doing it in the commented way (which also did not work) and forgot to swap the sign.